# Howto enable GPU-scaling with nVidia GTX 680 and UltraHD-DisplayPort-1.2-monitor?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gaming, displayport, display-driver

I am running a Dell UltraHD-monitor in 3840x2160 at 60 Hz (DisplayPort 1.2). [This monitor doesn’t support upscaling when running in DP 1.2 mode.](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN294781/EN)

nVidia's latest drivers seem to prevent GPU scaling for this setup. Therefore, I cannot play lots of old games (and some new games due to limited GPU performance) - well, I can play them, but only in a very tiny area of my screen.

**Is there a means to force the driver to enable GPU scaling in my setup?**

(GPU scaling seems to be disabled in DisplayPort 1.2 environments with nVidia)

Comment: @DanielB: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Mokubai: There is none that does. I think of this to be a limitation of nVidia and DisplayPort 1.2. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Mokubai: I do not quite understand your comment: DP1.2 is quite top-notch, and surely the maximum the display and card support. Thing is: nVidia seems to disable GPU scaling in that scenario. The question is: How might I overcome this, e.g. by forcing the driver into enabling GPU scaling despite DP1.2 being in use?

Comment: @DanielB: UP3214Q

Comment: @DanielB: And just to be sure: I really like that monitor's display quality, since it is incredibly sharp, clear and color matched - perfect for professional work. However, at times I would like to play an old or very recent FPS or two, but fail to - for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: To keep things clean, I added the info to your question and removed my comments. Quite shocking, too, I thought only some cheap Asian non-brands would lack scaling.

Comment: @Jinxed sorry, I got display port and HDMI mixed up. As you question is cleared up I am deleting my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I wasn't able to find any, there are many requests online and none was solved.

Additional info: I have the same problem with Dell UP2414Q.

The ways is to play games are:

- lower quality settings to play at 4K: a GTX 760 will be enough for most games, since you don't need complex antialias and FXAA is enough (at basically no performance cost),
- manually disable DP 1.2a before playing. In Windows the resolution of the desktop will be unaffected and you only lose the 60 Hz, that you will get back as soon as the game sets the resolution to 1080p. When done gaming, change again to DP 1.2a.

When playing multi-monitor games, if you play at 3x 4K, then you can leave DP 1.2a (f the graphics card manages it). If the side monitors are 1080p, you need to set 1080p also in the central monitor (see http://steamcommunity.com/app/244210/discussions/0/143387886726101309/). That means, you have only the second option mentioned above (unless you accept a black frame around the 1080p image, drawn at 4K without scaling).

Comment: The reason for me asking is, that I have a number of older games, which I really enjoyed, but cannot play anymore, since they do not even offer the option for going up to 4K, e.g. "No-one lives forever" etc.
Therefore, GPU-scaling is the only resolve, but obviously remains unsupported by nVidia (which I find rather disconcerting...)

Comment: @Jinxed as I wrote, you have to manually disable DP 1.2a in the monitor when you want to play and then the monitor will take care of upscaling. It's the only way. It takes only few seconds, after all.

Comment: Not quite, since the monitor's upscaling is so laggy, that playing is not possible anymore.